# Vuejs error: Property or method "products" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuex

Im new too nuxtjs and vuex, unfortunately i got some errors trying too fetch my data from vuex;

[Vue warn]: Property or method "products" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

./pages/index.vue

```
<template>
  
  <div>
    <TheCarousel />


    <SellingItems 
     v-for="prod in products"
     :key="prod.id"
     :id="prod.id"
     :image="prod.image"
     :name="prod.name"
     :price="prod.price"
    />
  </div>


</template>

<script>
import TheCarousel from '../components/TheCarousel'
import SellingItems from '../components/sellingItems'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  components: {
    TheCarousel,
    SellingItems
  },

  computed: {
    //  products(){
    //    return this.$store.getters['prods/products']
    //  }
     ...mapGetters(['prods/products'])
  }
}
</script>
```

./components/sellingItems.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container class="my-5">
    <h2>Top Selling Items</h2>
    <v-divider class="my-4"></v-divider>

    <v-row>
        <v-col
        sm="6"
        md="4"
        v-for="product in products"
        :key="product.name">
          <v-card outlined>
            <v-img :src="product.image" height="200px" />
            <v-card-title> {{ product.name}} </v-card-title>
            <v-card-subtitle> ${{ product.price }}</v-card-subtitle>

            <v-card-actions>
                          <v-btn color="success" outlined to="#">
                              <v-icon small left> add </v-icon>
                              Add to Cart
                          </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
   props: ['id', 'image', 'name', 'price'],
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

store/modules/product.js

```
export default {
    namsespaced: true,
    state(){
        return{
            products: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'Playstation 4', 
                    price: 200, 
                    image: 'img/ps4.jpg'
                },
                {
                    id: '2', 
                    name: 'Playstation 5', 
                    price: 700, 
                    image: 'img/ps5.jpg'
                },
                {
                    id: '3', 
                    name: 'Nintendo wii', 
                    price: 100, 
                    image: 'img/wii.jpg'
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    getters: {
        products(state){
            return state.products;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are passing in each item's properties into SellingItem but then in selling items, you are looping through `products` which does not exist in that component. Did you mean to use the passed in properties instead?

To use those passed in properties, reference them the same as if they were defined in `data` or `computed`:

```
    <v-row>
        <v-col sm="6" md="4">
          <v-card outlined>
            <v-img :src="image" height="200px" />
            <v-card-title> {{name}} </v-card-title>
            <v-card-subtitle> ${{price}}</v-card-subtitle>

            <v-card-actions>
                          <v-btn color="success" outlined to="#">
                              <v-icon small left> add </v-icon>
                              Add to Cart
                          </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

2. Your `mapGetters` is not defined correctly from within index.vue. Try this:

`...mapGetters('products', ['products'])`

And you would reference it like `this.products`.

The namespace would only be needed, from my understanding, if this Vuex store were nested in a parent store or if the getter was being called from within another Vuex store. For your example, calling with namespace from within a separate Vuex store's action would look like: `const value = context.rootGetters['products/products']`

Having said all of that, if your getter just returns the state item itself without any other logic, you might as well call the state item directly instead of going through a getter.

Comment: `...mapGetters('prods/products', ['products'])` does not seems right, since the OP named its vuex module 'prods', and it is a top one. his definition of mapGetters is legit. The issue is that mentioned by you in 1.

Comment: @IgorMoraru Thanks Igor, I was confused a bit by that. Wouldn't the namespace be `products` and not `prod` in this case?

Comment: Actually, the OP didn't show the namespace string. it is defined when the module is registered with the new Store. From the code posted, however, I'm assuming that it is 'prods', otherwise he would have gotten an error telling that the namespace does not exist.

Comment: @PerezMacdonald See updated answer. Things defined in `props` can be referenced the same as a `computed` or `data` property.